# How to check if a number is within range in activerecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a model with a range column

```
#<JobRequirement id: 1, age: 18...30>
```

How can I get the `JobRequirement` using an `age: 20`?

Something like

```
JobRequirement.where(age: 20)
```

Comment: Which database and what type is `age` inside the database?

Comment: It is int4range in postgreSQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to use the [PostgreSQL range operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE) and a bit of SQL in a string. In particular, you'd want the `@>` (contains element) operator:

```
JobRequirement.where('age @> ?', 20)
```

As far as supplying a range as a placeholder value goes:

```
JobRequirement.where('age <@ ?', 18..20)
```

you'll find that AR's knowledge of PostgreSQL's range types is somewhat limited. When you supply a range as a value for a placeholder, AR will want to expand the range to a comma delimited list as it assumes that you're saying something like `where('col in (?)', 18..20)` so you end up with nonsense like:

```
where age <@ 18,19,20
```

in the generated SQL. You can get around this by manually type casting the value; for example:

```
> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.type_cast(6..11)
 => "[6,11]" 
> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.type_cast(6...11)
 => "[6,11)"
```

and then sending the string into the query where PostgreSQL should cast it to a PostgreSQL-range automatically:

```
JobRequirement.where('age <@ ?', ActiveRecord::Base.connection.type_cast(18..20))
```

Depending on where you're doing this, the `connection` method might be available with all the noise:

```
JobRequirement.where('age <@ ?', connection.type_cast(18..20))
```

And if PostgreSQL isn't picking the right version of the `<@` operator on its own then you can help it with more typecasting:

```
JobRequirement.where('age <@ ?::int4range', connection.type_cast(18..20))
```

Comment: how about `Person.where('age <@ ?', 18..20)` ? I got an error `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer <@ integer`

Comment: This answer (although wonderful!) is somewhat outdated, now that Active Record supports range conditions: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#range-conditions